# Find memory leak when cancel a NSURLSession using https

Tags: ios

I want to upload a file with NSURLSessionUploadTask, and cancel the task when needed, it went well and the memory could be released when the upload was completed, but it seems that the memory was not released when the task was canceled, and even became a presistent memory. I started some tasks and canceled them when uploading, the memory became more and more high until got memory warning.

Object-C

```
@interface ViewController () <NSURLSessionDelegate>  

@property (nonatomic, weak) NSURLSessionUploadTask *task;  

@end  

@implementation ViewController  

- (void)viewDidLoad {  
    [super viewDidLoad];  
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.  

}  

- (IBAction)uploadAction:(UIButton *)sender {  

    @autoreleasepool {  
        NSString *token = @"";  
        NSString *key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"key=%d", arc4random() % 100000];  

        NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Pursue" ofType:@"mp3"];  
        NSString *fileName = [filePath lastPathComponent];  
        NSError *dataError = nil;  
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:&dataError];  
        if (dataError) return;  

        NSError *fileMError = nil;  
        NSDictionary *fileAttr = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:&fileMError];  
        if (fileMError) return;  

        QNUpToken *t = [QNUpToken parse:token];  
        if (!t) return;  

        NSMutableDictionary *parameters = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];  
        parameters[@"key"] = key;  
        parameters[@"token"] = t.token;  
        parameters[@"crc32"] = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%u", (unsigned int)[QNCrc32 data:data]];  

        NSURL *URL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"https://upload.qiniup.com"];  
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:URL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:30];  
        request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";  
        NSString *boundary = @"werghnvt54wef654rjuhgb56trtg34tweuyrgf";  
        request.allHTTPHeaderFields = @{  
                                        @"Content-Type" : [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary]  
                                        };  
        NSMutableData *postData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];  
        for (NSString *paramsKey in parameters) {  
            NSString *pair = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"\r\n\r\n", boundary, paramsKey];  
            [postData appendData:[pair dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  

            id value = [parameters objectForKey:paramsKey];  
            if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {  
                [postData appendData:[value dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  
            } else if ([value isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) {  
                [postData appendData:value];  
            }  
            [postData appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  
        }  
        NSString *filePair = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\nContent-Type:%@\r\n\r\n", boundary, @"file", fileName, @"application/octet-stream"];  
        [postData appendData:[filePair dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  
        [postData appendData:data];  
        [postData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];  
        [request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)postData.length] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];  
        [request setTimeoutInterval:15];  
        [request setValue:[[QNUserAgent sharedInstance] getUserAgent:t.access] forHTTPHeaderField:@"User-Agent"];  
        [request setValue:nil forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept-Language"];  

        NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];  
        __block NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];  
        _task = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request fromData:postData completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {  

            [session finishTasksAndInvalidate];  
        }];  
        [_task resume];  
    }  
}  

- (IBAction)cancelAction:(UIButton *)sender {  

    [_task cancel];  
}  

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task  
   didSendBodyData:(int64_t)bytesSent  
    totalBytesSent:(int64_t)totalBytesSent  
totalBytesExpectedToSend:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToSend {  
    NSLog(@"percent : %lld / %lld", totalBytesSent, totalBytesExpectedToSend);  
}
```

How can I release the memory when canceling a https session task.

Comment: Maybe the problem is in capturing session inside completion block? try making it weak

Comment: I have tried it，but not work..